# Are questions of the form "Is there a way to do ..." not allowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons

If I post those types of questions, they are closed as "seeking recommendations".

[Protecting Azure consumption plan from DDoS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67496648/azure-how-to-protect-consumption-plan-from-ddos-attacks)

**update** The close reason of the above question was changed.

Comment: How is that question related to programming? Sounds like server management to me

Comment: *I'm seeking a technical or mathematical proof of existence or non-existence of solutions.* I'm not sure what this means. Mathematical proof a DDoS attack can be prevented?

Comment: @Nick Do you develop systems which bankrupt customers by a large bill?

Comment: @BSMP The problem is to construct a solution if it exists, and if not exists, prove non-existence.

Comment: @BSMP I asked abstract question because concrete questions are not allowed. If I ask  "is there a tool such that ...", you say "You are seeking recommendation of tool!" and vote to close.

Comment: There is a huge gap between "Is there a way to do..." questions and that question. "Is there a way to post an HTML form using GET?" is a specific programming problem, answerable without information about external resources.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think there is a user on this site who think "This question is seeking recommendations of tools to post an HTML form using GET" and vote to close.

Comment: Hey, look, I get it, you want your question answered and someone told you we don't answer your kind of question. But getting all hyperbolic about it and trying to lump your question about how Microsoft sells Azure services in with every question whose title is phrased similarly is neither helpful nor ingenuous. You know you did something counter to the rules of the site you're on. Own up to that, accept it, and move on. Ask on one of [Microsoft's support boards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/products/azure?WT.mc_id=Portal-fx&product=all). There are other avenues than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PONPON - Abstract questions most definitely are not allowed.

Comment: @SecurityHound Haha, both abstract and concrete are not allowed. You can't post a questions.

Comment: If you post a concrete question, some users say "He is seeking recommendations of some company's product! Let's close it".

Comment: Software recommendations of any kind are out of scope, the problem isn’t with concrete questions, just your question unfortunately

Comment: @SecurityHound No. If you ask how to do X, and there is a tool to do X, someone says you are asking recommendation of that tool. My question is not asking recommendations as I have written.

Comment: @SecurityHound If I ask concrete solutions, you say "He is seeking recommendations of Cloudflare, Akamai, Azure DDoS Protection ,etc... let's close it." Hahaha, I have to ask abstractly.

Comment: see also [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: It's not a recommendation question; that was a poorly chosen close reason. rene is correct, though; the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it's not about programming. I've updated the close reason to be more accurate. Sorry about the confusion here. In general, "how to" questions are perfectly fine, as long as they're about programming, rather than server management and/or customer service.

Answer (score 17):

They are allowed under the assumption that "Is there a way to do..." generally covers…

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Above bullets are from [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Your specific question is asking about how you can protect a service offered on the web can be protected from DDoS attacks. You linked your question specific to the hosted service of Azure and their "consumption plan".

Please read [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) to understand why your question is already borderline. It is unlikely we can answer all ins and outs for the plans offered by Microsoft. Nor will an answer have long lasting value.

Hardening servers and services is a system management task, not a programming task. As such the question is off-topic here. It might fly on maybe Super User, Dev Ops or even Server Fault but check their helpcenters first.

Your question was closed correctly on Stack Overflow, despite that the title by itself is allowed.

Comment: I didn't know that designing a system with cost in mind is not "programming task". I'll post to other site.

Comment: @PONPON designing a system is a software engineering task. We have a site for that as well: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I think it's not restricted to a software problem.  However, I understand that English-language "programmer" doesn't think about cost of his programs.

Comment: Not sure what that little dig at English-speaking programmers is supposed to mean, @PONPON, but the fact remains that design decisions related to the cost of infrastructure do not fall within the scope of programming itself, which is what Stack Overflow intends to cover. As rene mentions, there are other sites for dealing with infrastructure (Dev Ops), server configuration (Server Fault), software architecture and design (Software Engineering), and more.